# String class cannot be cast to Node class

Tags: java, generics

I've got a homework assignment to refactor some code to use generics. I feel like I've done so correctly for the classes. Here is what I have

```
public class Node<T> {

    private T content;
    private T next;

    public Node(T content, T next) {
        this.content = content;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public T getNext() { return next; }

    public void setNext(T next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    private Node head;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
    }

    public void addFirst(T content) {
        Node<Object> ptr = head;
        head = new Node<>(content,ptr);
    }

    public void addLast(T content) {
        Node<Object> last = new Node<>(content,null);
        if (head == null) {
            head = last;
        } else {
            Node<Node> ptr = new Node(content, head);
            while(ptr.getNext() != null) {
                ptr = ptr.getNext();
            }
            ptr.setNext(last);
        }
    }
```

When it comes to the instantiation I get a ClassCastException error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class edu.cscc.Node (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; edu.cscc.Node is in unnamed module of loader 'app')"

Here is what I have in the main class which is causing the error.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list1();
        list2();
    }

    // Use linked list with Strings
    public static void list1() {
        LinkedList<String> llist = new LinkedList<String>();
        llist.addFirst("one");
        llist.addLast("two");
        llist.addLast("three");
        llist.addFirst("zero");
        llist.addLast("xxxx");
        llist.addFirst("yyyyy");
        llist.deleteLast();
        llist.deleteFirst();
        System.out.println(llist);
        llist.deleteFirst();
        llist.deleteLast();
        llist.deleteFirst();
        llist.deleteLast();
        System.out.println(llist);
    }

    // Use linked list with Integers
    public static void list2() {
        LinkedList<Integer> llist = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        llist.addFirst(1);
        llist.addLast(2);
        llist.addLast(3);
        llist.addFirst(0);
        llist.addLast(142);
        llist.addFirst(-97);
        llist.deleteLast();
        llist.deleteFirst();
        System.out.println(llist);
        llist.deleteFirst();
        llist.deleteLast();
        llist.deleteFirst();
        llist.deleteLast();
        System.out.println(llist);
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what is causing this?

Comment: can we see the full LinkedList class? But even if I comment out the functions that you have omitted I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Node`, your `next` variable is the wrong type:

```
public class Node<T> {

private T content;
private Node<T> next; // this is a reference to the next node

public Node(T content, Node<T> next) { // next is a Node<T>
    this.content = content;
    this.next = next;
}

...

public Node<T> getNext() { return next; }

public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}
```

Your `LinkedList` also needs to reference T more often:

```
public void addFirst(T content) {
    Node<T> ptr = head;
    head = new Node<T>(content, ptr);
}
```

And the logic for `addLast` seems weird when there is at least one item in the list already. You should find the last item in the list, then add a node after it.

```
Node<T> lastItem = head;
while(lastItem.getNext() != null) {
    lastItem = lastItem.getNext();
}
lastItem.setNext(new Node(content, last););
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've messed up a few types in your classes. You probably should have something like the following:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private final T content;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T content, Node<T> next) {
        this.content = content;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() { 
       return next; 
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public class LinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = null;
    }

    public void addFirst(T content) {
        head = new Node<>(content, head);
    }

    public void addLast(T content) {
        Node<T> last = new Node<>(content, null);
        if (head == null) {
            head = last;
        } else {
            Node<T> ptr = head;
            while (ptr.getNext() != null) {
                ptr = ptr.getNext();
            }
            ptr.setNext(last);
        }
    }
}
```